# Looping over the properties of Views (struct) in an Array is returning wrong values (init values)

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

I am using an array of Label-Views to display a ScrollView with all the Labels. When those Labels are tapped, they are selected and an `@State` boolean property in the Label-View is toggled. So at the bottom when a "Submit" Button is clicked, the values of the *selected* Labels are sent to a server.

In the "Submit" Button I am using a For-Loop to loop over the Label-Views and check for Labels that have `myLabel.isSelected == true`, but all of them are returning `false` even after being selected.

The main View simplified:

```
struct Sheet: View {
    
    @State var myLabels: [MyLabel] = [
        MyLabel(systemImage: "sparkles", text: "Keine Gebrauchsspuren"),
        MyLabel(systemImage: "checkmark.circle", text: "Minimale Gebrauchsspuren"),
        MyLabel(systemImage: "exclamationmark.circle", text: "Mehrere Gebrauchsspuren"),
        MyLabel(systemImage: "xmark.circle", text: "Starke Gebrauchsspuren"),
        MyLabel(systemImage: "arrow.down.to.line", text: "Delle(n)")

    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
              ForEach(myLabels, id: \.self) {label in label}
        }
        Button {
             var combinedString = ""
             for label in myLabels {
                   if label.isSelected {
                           combinedString += label.text 
                   }
             }
             postTextFunc(combinedString)
        } label: {
             Text("Submit")
        }
    }
```

The `combinedString` is always returning empty because when I iterate over the `myLabels` all the Labels have `isSelected` set to `false`. Is this because of how structs are handled by SwiftUI when their properties are changed? And how would I be able to reach my goal of returning the values of only the tipped Labels?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are structs in SwiftUI. So passing them into a function will create a copy of those Views. And you are itterating over the original Views that have not been modified.

I think a ViewModel/Model would be best here.

```
struct Model: Identifiable{
    var selected: Bool
    let text: String
    let id = UUID()
}

class Viewmodel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var models: [Model] = [] //Create the datamodel here
    
    func select(_ selectedModel: Model){
        var selectedModel = selectedModel
        selectedModel.selected.toggle() //Create a new copy and toggle selection
        
        // get index of selected item
        guard let index = models.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == selectedModel.id}) else{
            return
        }
        
        // assign item. This will toggle changes in the view
        models[index] = selectedModel
    }
    
func post(){
    //Create combined string
    let combinedString = models.filter{$0.selected}.reduce("") { partialResult, model in
        partialResult + model.text
    }
    //call post
    postTextFunc(combinedString)
}

func postTextFunc(_ string: String){
    
}
}

struct InnerView: View{
@EnvironmentObject private var viewmodel: Viewmodel
var selected: Model // provide the individual data here
var body: some View{
    Text(selected.text)
        .onTapGesture {
            viewmodel.select(selected)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View{
    
    @StateObject private var viewmodel = Viewmodel()
    
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(viewmodel.models, id: \.id) { model in
                    InnerView(selected: model)
                        .environmentObject(viewmodel) // pass viewmodel in environment
            }
        }
        Button {
            viewmodel.post()
        } label: {
             Text("Submit")
        }
    }
}
```